# Is it necessary to make any request to the facebook API, in order to make a react website

Tags: reactjs, facebook, rxjs

I started working on an already finished website, that was made using react, my job is just to fix things or add features.
As of recently I got a complaint that said there was a problem with one of the requests, upon further investigation i found out that there was a resquest being sent to facebook on the URL "https://www.facebook.com/tr/", I searched in the code and I couldn't find any reference to this URL, I also noticed that it happened everytime a button was pressed, and in some cases all the button did was change a the state of a variable and for some reason the facebook request still happened.
So I was wondering, since react was made from facebook, if it needs to perform a request to the facebook API, in order to access some of its features.

Comment: There isn't any request to facebook when you use reactjs.

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/tr/` returns just a 1x1 pixel GIF image, so this is likely some tracking pixel. It is unlikely though, that this request happens just because react was used; more likely, that some sort of tracking script was explicitly embedded.